# strange inputrc behavior: characters succeeding '1' being pushed to the end of the line

Tags: linux, bash, readline

I type in IP addresses frequently for my work. Most are on the same network, so it is fairly repetitive. I want to bind `F1` to the repetitive part of the IP, so I can just smack that and type in the rest. After identifying `F1`, I wrote a test `.inputrc`:

```
"1~":"foobar"
```

output:

```
foobar
```

This worked. I then wrote it with the intended functionality:

```
"1~":"146.184.4"
```

output:
    16.14.468

After some fiddling I realized that for any sequence of characters, numbers (or characters) succeeding a `1` were pushed to the end of the line.

Weird, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this configuration instead:

```
"\e[11~":"146.184.4"
```

I used the `readline(3)` manpage for that.